SQLAlchmey with MSSQL - Always Encrypted db is not working for like operator and concat function
I am working on Utility, where we are using MS-SQL DB with Always Encrypted and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server (Installed on Windows) to connect to data base, as per few Microsoft documentation it is recommended to pass Column Encrypted argument which is taken care as part of driver creation with my below code while executing the script, getting errors in the code snippet.
Anybody can help in SQLAlchemcy 1.3.17 version will support MS-SQL Always Encrypted and support query operations which I tried to validate with SQLAlchemcy.
**CODE : **
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import (Table)                        
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import func


Base = declarative_base()                   
metadata = MetaData()

db_url = "mssql+mxodbc://poc_alwaysencrypt:PBD!2342@TestODBCEncryption"
engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=False)

tbl_user = Table("users", metadata, autoload_with=engine)

class User(Base):
    __table__ = tbl_user    

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

try:
    user_idn = 179714
    user_obj = session.query(User.user_first_name, User.user_last_name, \
                func.concat(User.user_first_name, ',', User.user_last_name).label('full_name')).filter(User.user_idn==user_idn).one()
    print "**\n"
    print user_obj.user_first_name, user_obj.user_last_name, user_obj.full_name
except Exception, e:
    print "Error! ",  e
finally: session.close()

"""
Error!  (mx.ODBC.Error.ProgrammingError) ('22018', 206, "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: varchar(100) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'poc_alwaysencrypt') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2' is incompatible with varchar", 11159)
[SQL: SELECT user.user_first_name AS user_user_first_name, user.user_last_name AS user_user_last_name, concat(user.user_first_name, ?, user.user_last_name) AS full_name
FROM user
WHERE user.user_idn = ?]
[parameters: (',', 179714)]
"""

try:
    user_first_name = 'Bhagath'
    user_first_name = "%{}%".format(user_first_name)
    user_obj = session.query(User).filter(User.user_first_name.like(user_first_name)).one()
    print "user_first_nameuser_first_name\n"
    print user_obj.user_first_name, user_obj.user_last_name
except Exception, e:
    print "Error! ",  e
finally: session.close()


"""
Error!  (mx.ODBC.Error.ProgrammingError) ('22018', 206, "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: varchar(100) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'poc_alwaysencrypt') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2' is incompatible with varchar", 11159)
[SQL: SELECT user.user_first_name AS user_user_first_name, user.user_last_name AS user_user_last_name, concat(user.user_first_name, ?, user.user_last_name) AS full_name
FROM user
WHERE user.user_idn = ?]
[parameters: (',', 179714)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
Error!  (mx.ODBC.Error.ProgrammingError) ('42000', 33277, "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@P1', 'user_first_name'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'poc_alwaysencrypt') and the expression near line '3' expects it to be RANDOMIZED, a BIN2 collation for string data types, and an enclave-enabled column encr\x00v\x05\x00\x00\x00\x08\xee^\x00\xfeMA\xd5\xe8\xed^\x004\xee^\x00`\xff^", 11159)
[SQL: SELECT user.user_idn AS user_user_idn, user.user_first_name AS user_user_first_name, user.user_last_name AS user_user_last_name, user.user_middle_name AS user_user_middle_name, user.user_birth_dt AS user_user_birth_dt, user.user_gender_cd AS user_user_gender_cd
FROM user
WHERE user.user_first_name LIKE ?]
[parameters: ('%Bhagath%',)]
"""
   

Anybody has worked with Always Encrypted DB along with SQLAlchemcy, could  you suggest/recommend,  if anything missing in the above code to make it work.
I also changed engine url as below, execution of program failed during Table object initialization.
db_url = "mssql+mxodbc://poc_alwaysencrypt:PBD!2342@TestODBCEncryption?ColumnEncryption=Enabled;" 

